# Split a line from a CSV to a List<Key, Value>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a text file representing a CSV with a ';' being a separator. Here is a dummy dump for reference:

```
USER_EMPLOYEE_ID;SYSTEM1;USERNAME1;SYSTEM2;USERNAME2;SYSTEM3;USERNAME3;SYSTEM4;USERNAME4;SYSTEM5;USERNAME5;SYSTEM6;USERNAME6;SYSTEM7;USERNAME7;SYSTEM8;USERNAME8;SYSTEM9;USERNAME9;SYSTEM10;USERNAME10;SYSTEM11;USERNAME11;SYSTEM12;USERNAME12;SYSTEM13;USERNAME13;SYSTEM14;USERNAME14;SYSTEM15;USERNAME15;SYSTEM16;USERNAME16;SYSTEM17;USERNAME17;SYSTEM18;USERNAME18;SYSTEM19;USERNAME19;SYSTEM20;USERNAME20;SYSTEM21;USERNAME21;SYSTEM22;USERNAME22;SYSTEM23;USERNAME23;SYSTEM24;USERNAME24;SYSTEM25;USERNAME25;SYSTEM26;USERNAME26;SYSTEM27;USERNAME27;SYSTEM28;USERNAME28;SYSTEM29;USERNAME29;SYSTEM30;USERNAME30;SYSTEM31;USERNAME31;SYSTEM32;USERNAME32;SYSTEM33;USERNAME33;SYSTEM34;USERNAME34;SYSTEM35;USERNAME35;SYSTEM36;USERNAME36;SYSTEM37;USERNAME37;SYSTEM38;USERNAME38;SYSTEM39;USERNAME39;SYSTEM40;USERNAME40;SYSTEM41;USERNAME41;SYSTEM42;USERNAME42;SYSTEM43;USERNAME43;SYSTEM44;USERNAME44;SYSTEM45;USERNAME45;SYSTEM46;USERNAME46;SYSTEM47;USERNAME47;SYSTEM48;USERNAME48;SYSTEM49;USERNAME49;SYSTEM50;USERNAME50;SYSTEM51;USERNAME51;SYSTEM52;USERNAME52;SYSTEM53;USERNAME53;SYSTEM54;USERNAME54;SYSTEM55;USERNAME55;SYSTEM56;USERNAME56;SYSTEM57;USERNAME57;SYSTEM58;USERNAME58;SYSTEM59;USERNAME59;SYSTEM60;USERNAME60;SYSTEM61;USERNAME61;SYSTEM62;USERNAME62;SYSTEM63;USERNAME63;SYSTEM64;USERNAME64;SYSTEM65;USERNAME65;SYSTEM66;USERNAME66;SYSTEM67;USERNAME67;SYSTEM68;USERNAME68;SYSTEM69;USERNAME69;SYSTEM70;USERNAME70;SYSTEM71;USERNAME71;SYSTEM72;USERNAME72;SYSTEM73;USERNAME73;SYSTEM74;USERNAME74;SYSTEM75;USERNAME75;SYSTEM76;USERNAME76;SYSTEM77;USERNAME77;SYSTEM78;USERNAME78;SYSTEM79;USERNAME79;SYSTEM80;USERNAME80;SYSTEM81;USERNAME81;SYSTEM82;USERNAME82;SYSTEM83;USERNAME83;SYSTEM84;USERNAME84;SYSTEM85;USERNAME85;SYSTEM86;USERNAME86;SYSTEM87;USERNAME87;SYSTEM88;USERNAME88;SYSTEM89;USERNAME89;SYSTEM90;USERNAME90;SYSTEM91;USERNAME91;SYSTEM92;USERNAME92;SYSTEM93;USERNAME93;SYSTEM94;USERNAME94;SYSTEM95;USERNAME95;SYSTEM96;USERNAME96;SYSTEM97;USERNAME97;SYSTEM98;USERNAME98;SYSTEM99;USERNAME99;SYSTEM100;USERNAME100;SYSTEM101;USERNAME101;SYSTEM102;USERNAME102;SYSTEM103;USERNAME103;SYSTEM104;USERNAME104;SYSTEM105;USERNAME105;SYSTEM106;USERNAME106;SYSTEM107;USERNAME107;SYSTEM108;USERNAME108;SYSTEM109;USERNAME109;SYSTEM110;USERNAME110;SYSTEM111;USERNAME111;SYSTEM112;USERNAME112;SYSTEM113;USERNAME113;SYSTEM114;USERNAME114;SYSTEM115;USERNAME115;SYSTEM116;USERNAME116;SYSTEM117;USERNAME117;SYSTEM118;USERNAME118;SYSTEM119;USERNAME119;SYSTEM120;USERNAME120;SYSTEM121;USERNAME121;SYSTEM122;USERNAME122;SYSTEM123;USERNAME123;SYSTEM124;USERNAME124;SYSTEM125;USERNAME125;SYSTEM126;USERNAME126;SYSTEM127;USERNAME127
DGE3BLU;FS01;DGE3BLU;XHK218;DGE3BLU;XHP218;DGE3BLU;F3T103;DGE3BLU;FBP112;DGE3BLU;FBP112-1;DGE3BLU;F3D103;DGE3BLU;FSP100;DGE3BLU;FSP100-1;DGE3BLU;F3W103;DGE3BLU;FAT111;DGE3BLU;F3I103;DGE3BLU;FAK111;DGE3BLU;FAK111-1;DGE3BLU;FAK111-2;DGE3BLU;F3P103;DGE3BLU;F3P103-1;DGE3BLU;XHE218;DGE3BLU;FAW111;DGE3BLU;FAP111;DGE3BLU;FAP111-1;DGE3BLU;FAP111-2;DGE3BLU;F3K103;DGE3BLU;FKP111;DGE3BLU;FTP021;DGE3BLU;FAT113;DGE3BLU;F1P101;DGE3BLU;F1P101-1;DGE3BLU;FAT121;DGE3BLU;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
DGE3BMR;FS01;DGE3BMR;F3P103;DGE3BMR;F3P103-1;DGE3BMR;F1P101;DGE3BMR;F1P101-1;DGE3BMR;FSP100;DGE3BMR;FSP100-1;DGE3BMR;FBK112;DGE3BMR;FBK112-1;DGE3BMR;FAP111;DGE3BMR;FAP111-1;DGE3BMR;FAP111-2;DGE3BMR;FBT112;DGE3BMR;FBP112;DGE3BMR;FBP112-1;DGE3BMR;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
DGE3BOL;FS01;DGE3BOL;FAT111;DGE3BOL;FSQ100;DGE3BOL;FHI400;DGE3BOL;FSE100;DGE3BOL;F3K103;DGE3BOL;F1P101;DGE3BOL;F1P101-1;DGE3BOL;FHK222;DGE3BOL;FJI120;DGE3BOL;XHP218;DGE3BOL;F6P106;DGE3BOL;F3P103;DGE3BOL;F3P103-1;DGE3BOL;F1Q101;DGE3BOL;FTP021;DGE3BOL;F1K101;DGE3BOL;F1K101-1;DGE3BOL;FHE400;DGE3BOL;FAK111;DGE3BOL;FAK111-1;DGE3BOL;FAK111-2;DGE3BOL;FHP400;DGE3BOL;FSI100;DGE3BOL;FHE222;DGE3BOL;FSK100;DGE3BOL;FSK100-1;DGE3BOL;FAP111;DGE3BOL;FAP111-1;DGE3BOL;FAP111-2;DGE3BOL;FHI222;DGE3BOL;FSP100;DGE3BOL;FSP100-1;DGE3BOL;FHK400;DGE3BOL;FSD100;DGE3BOL;F6K106;DGE3BOL;FBP112;DGE3BOL;FBP112-1;DGE3BOL;FJK120;DGE3BOL;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
DGE3BOR;FS01;DGE3BOR;FSP100;DGE3BOR;FSP100-1;DGE3BOR;F6K106;DGE3BOR;FHP222;DGE3BOR;F3P103;DGE3BOR;F3P103-1;DGE3BOR;F4P104;DGE3BOR;F3T103;DGE3BOR;F4D604;DGE3BOR;FAP111;DGE3BOR;FAP111-1;DGE3BOR;FAP111-2;DGE3BOR;F6P106;DGE3BOR;FNK112;DGE3BOR;F3I103;DGE3BOR;FBK112;DGE3BOR;FBK112-1;DGE3BOR;F3D103;DGE3BOR;F3W103;DGE3BOR;FAE111;DGE3BOR;FAE111-1;DGE3BOR;FAE111-2;DGE3BOR;FPP126;DGE3BOR;F1K101;DGE3BOR;F1K101-1;DGE3BOR;FSI100;DGE3BOR;F7E107;DGE3BOR;F1Q101;DGE3BOR;F1P101;DGE3BOR;F1P101-1;DGE3BOR;FBE112;DGE3BOR;FBE112-1;DGE3BOR;F1F101;DGE3BOR;FSQ100;DGE3BOR;F5P105;DGE3BOR;FBP112;DGE3BOR;FBP112-1;DGE3BOR;F6E106;DGE3BOR;FJP120;DGE3BOR;F4K104;DGE3BOR;FBT112;DGE3BOR;F1F201;DGE3BOR;FHK222;DGE3BOR;FSK100;DGE3BOR;FSK100-1;DGE3BOR;F1W201;DGE3BOR;F3K103;DGE3BOR;F7T107;DGE3BOR;F6D106;DGE3BOR;FPK126;DGE3BOR;F7K107;DGE3BOR;F1W101;DGE3BOR;F4D104;DGE3BOR;FSD100;DGE3BOR;FHI222;DGE3BOR;FNP112;DGE3BOR;FSE100;DGE3BOR;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Now, the first column is a user identifier. For each user id here, I want generate a List of KeyValue pairs of all SYSTEMn and USERNAMEn that follow.

I have read the file as follows:

```
  using (var fs = File.Open(importFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
  {
    using (var bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
    {
      using (var sr = new StreamReader(bs))
      {
        String readLine;
        while ((readLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
          if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(readLine) || readLine == "---EOF---")
          {
            break;
          }

          // Data line
          var dataRow = readLine.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

          // Skip the first element as it the identifier.
          var rights = dataRow.Skip(1).Select(new {Key=?, Value=?}).ToList();

        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Which doesn't work that way. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the below link will help you 

http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16796/reading-only-two-out-of-three-columns-with-read-csv

Comment: The below link will help you, check it ......

[http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16796/reading-only-two-out-of-three-columns-with-read-csv][1]


  [1]: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16796/reading-only-two-out-of-three-columns-with-read-csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this

```
var lookup = dataRow.Skip(1)
    .Select((data, index) => new { lookup = index % 2, index = index, data = data})
    .ToLookup(d => d.lookup);

var rights = lookup[0].Join(lookup[1],
        system => system.index + 1,
        username => username.index,
        (system, username) => new
        {
            system = system.data,
            useraname = username.data
        })
        .Where(d => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.system))
        .ToDictionary(d => d.system, d => d.useraname);
```

Comment: Ok. It was my dream to grow up and use `.ToLookup()`. You made that `dream = true`.

Comment: @HassanGulzar ILookup can save you a lot of time when doing a lot of searches instead of List.Find(). I advise you to read about Dictionary and Lookup .

Answer (score 1):

**This gives USER_EMPLOYEE_ID with a list of KeyPair Values.**

```
var DataArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FilePath, Encoding.Default).Select(x => x.Split(';').ToArray()).ToArray();

var ResultList = new List<Tuple<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>>();

foreach (var Line in DataArray.Skip((1))) // Skip Header
{
    String USER_EMPLOYEE_ID = Line[0];
    var KVpairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();


    for (int i = 1; i < Line.Length; i += 2)
    {
        if (i + 1 < Line.Length)
            KVpairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(Line[i], Line[i + 1]));
    }

    ResultList.Add(Tuple.Create(USER_EMPLOYEE_ID, KVpairs));
}
```

Comment: This was applicable but since I was reading line by line and wanted to keep iteration minimal as these operation were being timed and in reality, the line-by-line data coming from within the while loop is running in a `Task<>`

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to do this via LINQ:

```
        List<string> data = new List(string);
        using (var fs = File.Open(importFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            using (var bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(bs))
                {
                    String readLine;
                    while ((readLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(readLine) || readLine == "---EOF---")
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                        data.Add(readLine);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var rights =
            data.Select(row => row.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.None))
                .SelectMany(GetData).ToList();
```

And create a private static method to get data from each line:

```
    private static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetData(string[] x)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < x.Length; i += 2)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x[i]) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x[i + 1])) 
                yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x[i], x[i + 1]);
        }
    }
```

Note you can't have the type of the list anonymous, since you need to use a private method in this solution. So I converted it for you to KeyValuePair, that already contains Key and Value.

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

As u got the list after skipping first element.....take two more list i.e 1) System 2) Username....

as per the result add the items if it is at odd place or even...

eg :

```
if(num % 2 == 0)
{
 // add to system
}
else
{
// add to username
}
```

Hope this will give u a path to continue.....