# Linq Lookup to parse a CSV text line

Tags: c#, linq, lookup

### Issue

I had asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23030001/481656) a while back and the requirements has changed a bit since then.

Now, there is a possibility to have a file with lines as follow:

```
Bryar22053;ADDPWN;Bryar.Suarez@company.com;ACTIVE
Nicole49927;ADDPWN;Nicole.Acosta@company.com;ACTIVE
Rashad58323;ADDPWN;Rashad.Everett@company.com;ACTIVE
```

Take first line. The first value `Bryar22053` is skipped and the same lookup is used:

```
var columnCount = dataRow.Skip(1).Count();
var modular = 0;

// Simple Enum
var rightsFileType = new RightsFileType();

if (columnCount % 2 == 0)
{
    rightsFileType = RightsFileType.WithoutStatus;
    modular = 2;
}
else if (columnCount % 3 == 0)
{
    rightsFileType = RightsFileType.WithStatus;
    modular = 3;
}

var lookup = dataRow.Skip(1).Select((data, index) => new
{
    lookup = index % modular,
    index,
    data
}).ToLookup(d => d.lookup);
```

The lookup object now has three groups:

```
> ? lookup[0].ToList() Count = 1
>     [0]: { lookup = 0, index = 0, data = "ADDPWN" } ? lookup[1].ToList() Count = 1
>     [0]: { lookup = 1, index = 1, data = "Bryar.Suarez@company.com" } ? lookup[2].ToList() Count = 1
>     [0]: { lookup = 2, index = 2, data = "ACTIVE" }
```

[image: Debugging]

If it was the original case where it would be just System1,User1,System2,User2... the `lookup` would have two groups and following code would work:

```
List<RightObjectRetrieved> rights;
rights = lookup[0].Join(lookup[1], system => system.index + 1, username => username.index, (system, username) => new
{
    system = system.data,
    useraname = username.data
}).Where(d => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.system)).Select(d => new RightObjectRetrieved {UserIdentifier = userIdentifier, SystemIdentifer = d.system, Username = d.useraname, RightType = rightsFileType}).ToList();

// rights => Key = System Identifier, Value = Username
```

But with the third 'status' as System1,User1,**Status1**,System2,User2,**Status2**..., I'm having issue trying to Join and get all three. Please help.

**Edit**
Here is what I have for raw data:

```
// Method has parameter localReadLine (string) that has this:
// Bryar22053;ADDPWN;Bryar.Suarez@company.com;ACTIVE

// Data line
var dataRow = localReadLine.Split(new[] { ToolSettings.RightsSeperator }, StringSplitOptions.None);

// Trim each element
Array.ForEach(dataRow, x => dataRow[Array.IndexOf(dataRow, x)] = x.Trim());
```

### Tried (failed) so far

```
rights = lookup[0].Join(lookup[1], system => system.index + 1, username => username.index, status => status.index, (system, username, status) => new
{
    system = system.data,
    useraname = username.data,
    status = status.data
}).Where(d => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.system)).Select(d => new RightObjectRetrieved {UserIdentifier = userIdentifier, SystemIdentifer = d.system, Username = d.useraname, RightType = rightsFileType}).ToList();
```

And

```
rights = lookup[0].Join(lookup[1], system => system.index + 1, username => username.index, (system, username) => new
{
    system = system.data,
    useraname = username.data
}).Join(lookup[2], status => status.index, (status) => new
{
    status = status.data
}).Where(d => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.system)).Select(d => new RightObjectRetrieved {UserIdentifier = userIdentifier, SystemIdentifer = d.system, Username = d.useraname, RightType = rightsFileType, Status = ParseStatus(status)}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to split up a little bit your implementation.

Let's declare a class that will hold the data:

```
class Data
{
    public string System { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Now, let's define a couple of parsing functions to parse a line.
The first one will parse a line which includes status:

```
var withStatus = (IEnumerable<string> line) => line
    .Select((token, index) => new { Value = token, Index = index })        
    .Aggregate(
        new List<Data>(),
        (list, token) =>
        {
            if( token.Index % 3 == 0 )
            {
                list.Add(new Data { System = token.Value });
                return list;
            }
            var data = list.Last();
            if( token.Index % 3 == 1 )
                data.Username = token.Value;
            else
                data.Status = token.Value;
            return list;
        });
```

The second one will parse a line which doesn't include status:

```
var withoutStatus = (IEnumerable<string> line) => line
    .Select((token, index) => new { Value = token, Index = index })
    .Aggregate(new List<Data>(),
        (list, token) => 
        {
            if( token.Index % 2 == 0)
                list.Add(new Data { System = token.Value });
            else
                list.Last().Username = token.Value;
            return list;
        });
```

With all that in place, you'll need the following:

1. Determine the modulus
2. Iterate the lines of the file and parse each line
3. Group and aggregate the results

The remaining code would look like this:

```
var lines = streamReader.ReadAllLines(); // mind the system resources here!
var parser = lines.First().Split(';').Length % 2 == 0 ? withoutStatus : withStatus;
var data = lines.Skip(1) // skip the header
    .Select(line =>
    {
        var parts = line.Split(';');
        return new
        {
            UserId = parts.First(),
            Data = parser(parts.Skip(1))
        };
    })
    .GroupBy(x => x.UserId)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.SelectMany(x => x.Data));
```

Now you have a `Dictionary<string, Data>` which holds the user id and its info.

Of course, a more elegant solution would be to separate each parsing function into its own class and join those classes under a common interface in case there would be more info to add in the future but the code above should work and give you an idea of what you should do.

Comment: I'm not able to use your code as-is: http://i.imgur.com/1zhFNuF.png

Cannot assign lambda expression to an implicitly-typed variable

Comment: @HassanGulzar, change `var` to `Func<IEnumerable<string>, List<Data>>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use joins:

```
var result = lookup[0]
    .Join(lookup[1],
        system => system.index,
        username => username.index - 1,
        (system, username) => new {system = system.data, username = username.data, system.index})
    .Join(lookup[2],
        d => d.index,
        status => status.index - 2,
        (d, status) => new {d.system, d.username, status = status.data})
    .ToList();
```

Another option to group by records and just select data from it (looks more readable from my point of view):

```
var result = dataRow
    .Skip(1)
    .Select((data, index) => new {data, record = index / 3})
    .GroupBy(r => r.record)
    .Select(r =>
    {
        var tokens = r.ToArray();
        return new
        {
            system = tokens[0].data,
            username = tokens[1].data,
            status = tokens[2].data
        };
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Added .Skip(1) (it was missed, I assumed that it should be added similar to your initial code)